# Notification with NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsnotificationcenter

My code :

popover.m

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self.playersSelected addObject:[self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didChangePlayerList:)
                                                 name:@"sth"
                                               object:self.playersSelected];

}
```

VC.m

```
-(void)didchangePlayerList:(NSNotification *)notification {

    self.temporaryArray
}
```

I want to get notify i my VC and add object to temporaryArray then when it's added in playersSelected. How to do it best?

Comment: Look at `[notification object]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with notification but I think you should use a [delegate](http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002).

In your popover.m : (didSelectRowAtIndexPath)

```
[self.playersSelected addObject:[self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[userInfo setObject:[self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"object"];

// Send parameters with userInfo
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didChangePlayerList" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

In your VC.m : (viewDidLoad)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleDidChangePlayerList:) name:@"didChangePlayerList" object:nil];
```

and

```
- (void)handleDidChangePlayerList:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;

    [self.temporaryArray addObject:[userInfo valueForKey:@"articleId"]];
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to delete objects from temporaryArray when is called didDeselect ?

Comment: You can use the same purpose. But you send the object to delete and call [self.temporaryArray removeObject:object];

Comment: [self.playersSelected removeObject:[self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificationMessageEvent2" object:[self.playersSelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; dosent work

Comment: send [self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] and not [self.playersSelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]